# Getting NullPointerException while displaying ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, listview-adapter

I was trying to make a ListView of reminder notes. But when I try to save it and display it in a ListView, app crashes with this error/exception. `saveNote` method is called when you press save button. Any help is appreciated.

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch(id) {
      case R.id.add_reminder : {
          et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_note);
          et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          note = et.getText().toString();
          i++;
          Button save_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save);
          save_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
      default : return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

}
public void saveNote(View view) {

    String[] notes = new String[20];
    notes[i] = note;
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,notes);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //Clicked item index
            int itemPosition = position;
            //Clicked item value
            String itemNote = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            //Alert
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position :" + itemPosition + "  ListItem : " + itemNote, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Logcat

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at com.cokosofts.pramith.reminder.MainActivity.saveNote(MainActivity.java:69)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: What do mean by `notes[i] = note;` line? only `ith` element in Array is not Null and rest is null

Comment: I checked a few related question posted here. But it was a bit different and I could not figure out the solution.

Comment: `notes[i] = note;` what does it means? what is `i` and `note`?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K Yes. Will it be a problem to dynamically assign it each time the user enter notes? Rest will be null.

Comment: @Rustam `i` is set as integer. `note` a string

Comment: @PramithS: yes this is problem

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K Can you suggest a solution to that. How can I add notes so that it won't be an error/exception.

Comment: paste your logcat...

Comment: @Chintan Rathod Here is the Logcat

Comment: Sorry. I have just pasted Logcat as it is. I don't know the proper way to insert it here.

Comment: @Pramith S ...try to change it as..
`ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivitythis, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,notes);`

Comment: i think context is the problem...

Comment: @PramithS: and also make sure ListView with `list` is present in current Activity Layout

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K Thank you for your suggestions. I created the ListView in a separate layout file. That was the problem.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The main cause which I found from the Logs is ListView is null. Please  check one more time if the listView is empty or not? Also what is `notes[i] = note`  ??
I think in each Save button click you are finding ListView and the setting Adapter each  time. This is not a  good  approach from my point of  view. You  should  set the adapter very first time and next time  just update your adapter data and  call notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

Debug and find out why your ListView was not found on your layout (was null).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with following line:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Please check whether your xml has ListView widget with id as `'list'` .
If id is different in XML it will result in a NULL object reference. When you call

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter)
```

It will give a NULL pointer exception.